# Can we get the slected options Text of select menu using jquery "Dynamic option values"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to show the drop value text but the thing is these values are dynamic,what is the correct way to approach,and right now only **id** values are coming now.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="wp-form-control" id="joblocation" name="joblocation">
        <option value="0">Select Job Location</option>
        <?php  $City = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cities  ORDER BY city_pid ASC");
            while ($Cityresult = $City->fetch_assoc()) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $Cityresult['city_pid']; ?>"> <?php echo $Cityresult['city_name']; ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

And Script:

```
var joblocation = $('#joblocation').find(":selected").text();
$("#joblocation1").html(joblocation);
```

And i want to show the dropdown selected text here:

```
<span id="joblocation1"> </span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
//This is for debugging and will show you the selected option object in console
console.info($("#joblocation option:selected") );

$("#joblocation1").html($("#joblocation option:selected").text() );
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
 var optionText = $("#joblocation option:selected").text() //gets you the text from the selected option
```

And then add the variable to the span like so:

```
$("#joblocation1").text(optionText);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".